# How to make multiple AND conditions in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to display entries between two dates.  Dates are stored in this format `'dd/mm/YYYY'`.

```
meta_id |    post_id |   meta_key         | meta_value  
5652    |    510     | _begin_date_course | 04/02/2018  
5756    |    512     | _begin_date_course | 04/02/2018  
5889    |    510     | _end_date_course   | 11/03/2019  
6002    |    512     | _end_date_course   | 04/02/2019  
..
```

I'm trying to return a `post_id` between the two dates.

If i try this :

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE (meta_key = '_begin_date_course' AND STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') >= '2019-02-04')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE (meta_key = '_end_date_course' AND STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') <= '2020-06-06')
```

It's working.

But if I try with a AND format, it's not working

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE (meta_key = '_begin_date_course' AND STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') >= '2019-02-04')
AND (meta_key = '_end_date_course' AND STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') <= '2020-06-06')
```

Is it maybe because _begin_date_course and _end_date_course are in two different entries.

**How can I get a post_id in a range in this condition?**

Comment: Are you sure the difference in year (2018 in data and 2019 in query) is intended?

Comment: Your query will be slow :(

Answer (score 0):

If what you only need is the list of `post_id` that correspond to your criteria, you can use aggregation, with a `HAVING` clause to do the filtering, like:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING 
        MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_begin_date_course' THEN STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') END) >= '2019-02-04'
    AND MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_end_date_course'   THEN STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') END) <= '2020-06-06'
```

---

On the other hand, if you want to return the entire records, here is a solution using window functions, available since MySQL 8.0.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        p.*, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_begin_date_course' THEN STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') END) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY post_id) begin_date_course,
        MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_end_date_course'   THEN STR_TO_DATE(meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') END) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY post_id) end_date_course
    FROM wp_postmeta
) x
WHERE begin_date_course >= '2019-02-04' AND end_date_course <= '2020-06-06'
```

The subquery recovers the begin and end date that correspond to each record, and the outer query does the filtering on dates.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a query like this:

```
SELECT
      p1.post_id
    , p1.meta_value as date_start
    , p2.meta_value as date_end
FROM wp_postmeta p1
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta p2 ON p1.post_id = p2.post_id AND p2.meta_key = '_end_date_course'
WHERE 
    p1.meta_key = '_begin_date_course'
AND
     STR_TO_DATE(p1.meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') >= '2018-02-04'
AND
     STR_TO_DATE(p2.meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') <= '2020-06-06';
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from wp_postmeta;
+----+---------+--------------------+------------+
| id | post_id | meta_key           | meta_value |
+----+---------+--------------------+------------+
|  1 |     510 | _begin_date_course | 04/02/2018 |
|  2 |     512 | _begin_date_course | 04/02/2018 |
|  3 |     510 | _end_date_course   | 11/03/2019 |
|  4 |     512 | _end_date_course   | 04/02/2019 |
+----+---------+--------------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT   p1.post_id
    -> , p1.meta_value as date_start
    -> , p2.meta_value as date_end
    -> FROM wp_postmeta p1
    -> LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta p2 ON p1.post_id = p2.post_id AND p2.meta_key = '_end_date_course'
    -> WHERE 
    -> p1.meta_key = '_begin_date_course'
    -> AND
    ->  STR_TO_DATE(p1.meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') >= '2018-02-04'
    -> AND
    ->  STR_TO_DATE(p2.meta_value, '%d/%m/%Y') <= '2020-06-06';
+---------+------------+------------+
| post_id | date_start | date_end   |
+---------+------------+------------+
|     510 | 04/02/2018 | 11/03/2019 |
|     512 | 04/02/2018 | 04/02/2019 |
+---------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```